# Error executing: bench --site site1.local install-app erpnext

Tags: python, setup-deployment, erp, erpnext, frappe

I am trying to install ERPNext frappe using full installation, but facing the following issue while executing bench --site site1.local install-app erpnext

I am using `ubuntu-19.04 OS`.

I am using `master branch`.

```
bench --site site1.local install-app erpnext
```

error shows

> Installing erpnext... Updating DocTypes for erpnext : [ ]Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/utils/bench_helper.py", line 97, in  main() File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/utils/bench_helper.py", line 18, in main click.Group(commands=commands)(prog_name='bench') File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in **call** return self.main(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main rv = self.invoke(ctx) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx)) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx)) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke return callback(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/commands/**init**.py", line 25, in _func ret = f(frappe._dict(ctx.obj), *args, **kwargs) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/commands/site.py", line 168, in install_app _install_app(app, verbose=context.verbose) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/installer.py", line 145, in install_app sync_for(name, force=True, sync_everything=True, verbose=verbose, reset_permissions=True) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/sync.py", line 56, in sync_for reset_permissions=reset_permissions, for_sync=True) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/modules/import_file.py", line 65, in import_file_by_path ignore_version=ignore_version, reset_permissions=reset_permissions) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/modules/import_file.py", line 100, in import_doc doc = frappe.get_doc(docdict) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/**init**.py", line 730, in get_doc doc = frappe.model.document.get_doc(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/document.py", line 69, in get_doc return controller(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/document.py", line 113, in **init** super(Document, self).**init**(kwargs) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/base_document.py", line 54, in **init** self.update(d) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/base_document.py", line 77, in update self.set(key, value) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/base_document.py", line 124, in set self.extend(key, value) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/base_document.py", line 161, in extend self.append(key, v) File "/home/jeet/ERPNEXT-SETUP/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/model/base_document.py", line 155, in append self.name, str(type(value))[1:-1], value) ValueError: Document for field "field_order" attached to child table of "Accounts Settings" must be a dict or BaseDocument, not type 'unicode' (auto_accounting_for_stock)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZNr8.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvyqy.png]

Answer (score 0):

did you first try locating the actual site name?
Is is called site1.local or is it simply called site1?

I find that sometimes, it's the site name that causes an issue with launching Bench commands.

Also kindly ensure that you are changed the directory into the frappe-bench folder.

Finally, it also seems that you may have some permission issues as well.